# jQuery select not working in Meteor 1.1.0.2 onRendered

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am working on an app I had deployed, and trying to get everything up to the latest version and update the code to take advantage of the latest processes, like subscribing in the Template.onRendered, but I have seemingly broken my sortable.

My template (simplified somewhat)

```
<template name="formEdit">
  <div id="formContainer">
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
      {{#with form this}}
        <table id="headerFieldsTable" class="table">
          <tbody id="headerFields">
            {{#each headerFields}}
              <tr class="headerFieldRow">
                <td>{{> headerFieldViewRow }}</td>
              </tr>
            {{/each}}
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <h5>Form Fields</h5>
        <table id="formFieldsTable" class="table">
          <tbody id="formFields">
            {{#each formFields}}
              <tr class="formFieldRow">
                <td>{{> formFieldViewRow }}</td>
              </tr>
            {{/each}}
          </tbody>
        </table>

      {{/with}}
    {{else}}
      Loading...
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>
```

And the template's onRendered():

```
Template.formEdit.onRendered(function() {
  var formsSubscription = this.subscribe('formById', this.data);
  var headerFieldsSubscription = this.subscribe('headerFieldsForForm', this.data);
  var formFieldsSubscription = this.subscribe('formFieldsForForm', this.data);

  var formEditTemplate = this;
  this.autorun(function() {
    if (formsSubscription.ready() && headerFieldsSubscription.ready() && formFieldsSubscription.ready()) {
formEditTemplate.$(''));
      formEditTemplate.$('#headerFields').sortable({
        axis: "y",
        stop: function(event, ui) {
          var headersToSave = [];
          $('#headerFieldsTable div.headerField').each(function(idx, headerFieldDiv) {
            var header = Blaze.getData(headerFieldDiv);
            header.sequence = idx;
            headersToSave.push(header);
          });
          _.each(headersToSave, function(header) { header.save(); });
        }
      });

      formEditTemplate.$('#formFields').sortable({
        axis: "y",
        stop: function(event, ui) {
          var feildsToSave = [];
          $('#formFieldsTable div.formField').each(function(idx, formFieldDiv) {
            var field = Blaze.getData(formFieldDiv);
            field.sequence = idx;
            feildsToSave.push(field);
          });
          _.each(feildsToSave, function(field) { field.save(); });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

But for both the headers and footers, the `formEditTemplate.$('#headerFields')` and `formEditTemplate.$('#formFields')` both seem to return no results.  It seems like the DOM is not actually present.  I thought the `.ready()` call on all the subscriptions would correct that, but think there is a timing issue where Blaze hasn't fixed up the DOM yet, but the subscriptions are indeed done.  I say this because I put a breakpoint in Chrome right at the first line of the `if`, and the browser was still showing "Loading...".

I also attempted to hot-wire things by having a helper that setup the sortable placed at the end of the `{{#with}}` block, hoping that maybe it would be rendered last, but that didn't work either.

I found some articles on the Meteor forums that seemed to suggest adding a timer, but this seems very "hackish".  Is there a new pattern for running JS that requires the DOM to be fully initialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the time delay hack, I recommend you use `Tracker.afterFlush()` to guarantee that the DOM has been created and updated. Here is a description from [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_afterflush):

> Schedules a function to be called during the next flush, or later in
>   the current flush if one is in progress, after all invalidated
>   computations have been rerun. The function will be run once and not on
>   subsequent flushes unless afterFlush is called again.

So inside of your `if` statement, you can wrap the code block like so

```
if (formsSubscription.ready() && headerFieldsSubscription.ready() && formFieldsSubscription.ready()) {
  Tracker.afterFlush( function () {
    //Code block to be executed after subscriptions ready AND DOM updated
  });
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Tracker-Manual) is a reference with examples using `Tracker.afterFlush`.

Comment: I don't know why I always forget `Tracker.afterFlush()` exists. Thanks, this worked perfectly.