# meteor call jquery inside a onrendered template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, meteor

I want to include a script using `jquery` inside the `onRendered` function on a template.

this is the code

```
Template.Admin_users.onRendered(function(){
    var instance = this;
    instance.autorun(function(){
        if($){
            console.log($);
            console.log("jquery");
            $("#Users.collection-item").click();    
            $.getScript(
                "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"
                //'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places'
                , function(){
                    console.log("loaded gmap");
                    var acs = $(".citycomplete").length;
                    for(var i = 0 ;i<acs;i++){
                        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($(".citycomplete")[i], {});
                        autocomplete.id = $(".citycomplete")[i].id;
                        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                            $("input[name=lat]#"+autocomplete.id).val(place.geometry.location.lat());
                            $("input[name=lng]#"+autocomplete.id).val(place.geometry.location.lng());
                        });
                    }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

The problem is that `jquery` (and gmap) does not load on the page refresh. If I change template (loading another route) and then coming back to this `Admin_users` template, `jquery` and gmap will load. How can I load `jquery` on page load?

I've seen a lot of questions here in SO about this problem but none of them seems to work for me([solution one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642384/jquery-select-not-working-in-meteor-1-1-0-2-onrendered) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410615/meteor-template-onrendered-or-template-rendered-for-using-a-jquery-library) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205087/jquery-ui-effect-with-meteor-onrendered-callback-not-working) [four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205087/jquery-ui-effect-with-meteor-onrendered-callback-not-working))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no need to put that code into an `autorun` if there is no reactive variable that would trigger a rerun. Also you don't want it to rerun multiple times correct? If so, remove the `autorun`. What you can do is to wait a bit.

```
Template.Admin_users.onRendered(function(){
    Meteor.setTimeout(()=>{doYourThing()}, 500);
});
```

Does that help?

Comment: yes. that worked. even without waiting 500 ms Meteor.setTimeout(()=>{doYourThing()}, 0);

Comment: Strange that the `Meteor.defer` solution did not work for you then, bc that is just a convenience function for setTimeout with 0 delay. Anyways, glad I could help.